# Degree of Polarizaton

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

If we consider a mixture of an unpolarized light with intensity $\ I_u $ and a polarized light with intensity $\ I_p $.
Is the intensity of whole mixture $ I=(\sqrt I_p + \sqrt I_u)^2 $, where amplitudes are added algebraically (assuming that waves are travelling in same direction)
or do we have to use some other way to calculate it?

Is the intensity of mixture as a whole even defined?

I am asking this question because I read about degree of polarization of a mixture which is defined in  terms of its $\sqrt I_{max} $ and $\sqrt I_{min}$.

What do $\sqrt I_{max}$  etc mean here and how is it calculated?

P.S-  I have recently started studying polarization of waves and there is not a lot of theory which I could find on mixtures, any reference to guide if this question is too basic also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpolarized light means, that any polarization is equiprobable.

You may think about it in a following way - imagine the circle, and arrow on it, and the angle between this arrow and say $x$-axis is $\varphi$. The total amplitude of electromagnetic wave, with the polarization vector having an angle in interval $(\varphi, \varphi + d \varphi)$ is:
$$
\frac{d \varphi}{2 \pi} \sqrt{I_u}
$$
Let us align the $x$-axis with the polarized wave. The amplitude of sum of the polarized wave and the part of the unpolarized wave directed in $(\varphi, \varphi + d \varphi)$  can be obtained by the usual way of vector summation.

Let us divide the polarized vector into small segments of length $
\frac{d \varphi}{2 \pi} \sqrt{I_p}
$ and unpolarized into segments of length $\frac{d \varphi}{2 \pi} \sqrt{I_u}$, then the net intensity is:
$$
\int \frac{d \varphi}{2 \pi} (\sqrt{I_p + I_u + 2 \sqrt{I_p \ I_u} \cos \phi})^2=
\int \frac{d \varphi}{2 \pi} (I_p + I_u + 2 \sqrt{I_p \ I_u} \cos \phi ) = I_p + I_u
$$
The intereference term vanishes - therefore the net insensity of the sum of intensities.

Comment: I think this answers the question. Though I have a little difficulty understanding it. So, basically the net intensity comes out as sum of intensities is because the interference term cancels out which means that no interference takes place?  Why can't the same argument be followed in usual case where net intensity comes as square of sum of individual ampltiudes?

Comment: Maybe can you add a contrast in your answer from the case I've mentioned (which I'm referring to as 'usual case') and highlight what makes these cases different.

Comment: @Lost In the case of two fully polarized waves the total amplitude is a vector sum of each particular amplitude, where the angle $\varphi$ between the amplitudes accounts for the angle between two polarizations. It is like and addition of complex numbers. If the polarizations match, two vectors are aligned in the same direction, and the total amplitude is the sum of the individual amplitudes. Then the intensity is simply $(\sqrt{I_1} + \sqrt{I_2})^2$. In the case of opposite polarisations, the net amplitude is obtained by subtraction, and the intensity : $(\sqrt{I_1} - \sqrt{I_2})^2$.

Comment: @Lost in the unpolarized case one gets something in between, loosely speaking